# Android: Pressing ad causes Activity with locked orientation to change orientation

Tags: android, screen-orientation, onconfigurationchanged

All of the Activities in my app are locked into portrait orientation using:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

I have ads showing at the top of a few of my Activities, and if I tilt the phone sideways and press the ad, it changes the underlying Activity into landscape orientation! I tried to override

```
onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
```

by setting the configuration to portrait and calling through to super, but it has no effect. Any clue on how to fix this, or what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

Did the trick.